# How to set onclick repeat automatically? or it auto repeat functions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The situation now is:

I have a button,when it is clicked, it sends its id to php page,then,clean the table and print a new table append to the column.

The problem i am now facing is that,i would like to automatically update the table for every 30 seconds after the button is clicked,but not manually click it again myself. I have tried setTimeOut but it stopped showing table instead of updating it every time interval.

my HTML button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ETArequest(this) " id="d1stop" class="list-group-item" style="text-align:center; height:30px; font-size:15px;"></button>
```

my JavaScript:

```
function ETArequest(button) {
 if (button == "") {
    $('#ETAcol').empty();
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            $('#ETAcol').empty();
            $('#ETAcol').append(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getTime.php?q="+(button.id),true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}}
```

Comment: did your try `setInterval()` ?

Comment: @Adam Tried setInterval,in various way. declare a new function such as function repeat(button){var repeat = setInterval(function(){ETArequest(button),2000});} but it shows nothing. and changed the onclick function to repeat(button)

Comment: It would be pleased if more details/ solutions can be given,thank you guys

Comment: Do NOT use setInterval(), especially when you send AJAX requests. In case the response takes more than the set interval, you could overload the browsers.

Comment: @RadekPech I have tried and that failed, what would you recommend? I would like to renew the data entry and print it on the screen. Simple as that. ( i have another project keep updating the database value,and i would like to print that with time interval update without reclicking the button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you set the timeout. Best way to repeat function calls is:

```
var 
    delay = 30000,
    f = function() {
        ETArequest($('button'));
        setTimeout(f, delay);
    };
setTimeout(f, delay);
```

This way you will start new waiting only after the function finished.

However, in your case - when you send asynchronous request, you should start the timeout AFTER the request finishes:

```
var 
    delay = 30000,
    f = function() {
        ETArequest($('button'), f, delay);
    };
setTimeout(f, delay);

function ETArequest(button, callback, delay) {
    //... YOUR CODE

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            $('#ETAcol').empty();
            $('#ETAcol').append(xmlhttp.responseText);
            setTimeout(callback, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Also do not forget that you must correctly set scope and params for the function!

If you use jQuery to send AJAX, you can use it like this:

```
var 
    delay = 30000,
    f = function() {
        ETArequest($('button')).always(function() { setTimeout(f, delay); });
    };
setTimeout(f, delay);

function ETArequest(button, callback, delay) {
    //... YOUR CODE

    return $.ajax(url, options);
}
```

Function ajax returns a promise - if you pass a function into its always method, it will be called after the ajax finished. See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for details.

To start and stop the autoupdate:

```
function autoupdate() {
    var 
        delay = 30000,
        f = function() {
            ETArequest($('button'), f, delay);
        };

    if (!window.autoupdate) {
        window.autoupdate = setTimeout(f, delay);
        $('button').text('Stop');
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(window.autoupdate);
        window.autoupdate = false;
        $('button').text('Update');
    }
}
```

And in the XHR response:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        $('#ETAcol').empty();
        $('#ETAcol').append(xmlhttp.responseText);

        if (false !== window.autoupdate) {
            setTimeout(callback, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

And the button will work as both start and stop:

```
<button id=start onclick="autoupdate();">Update</button>
```

Explanation: when you click the Stop button, you need to clear the timeout but also to remember that the autoupdate was already stopped not to start a new one in case you clicked stop while the browser is waiting for response (and no timer is running).

Comment: Sorry i am relatively novice, i am not quite understand how you declare the  whole thing and how this stuff work.
var delay = 30000, is that comma a semicolon?

Comment: No, that is really comma. It is used to define more variable in a single VAR, which is preferred way of declaring variables - all in single VAR on the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what would be the parameter input call back and delay when i clicked the button? how to use the var delay part as once i clicked the button, it starts the function rather than going through from above right?

Comment: The code here should be put into a function, e.g. function autoupdate() { ... }; . Then in the button onclick you should call this autoupdate function to start it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do i clearTimeout as the variable name is too complicated for me to understand?

Comment: I've added code for the autoupdate function with both start and stop functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive what you desire with setInterval as another user has already recommended, maybe an example will assist you.

```
function doRequest(button){
  var button_id = button;
  var intervalToRun = setInterval(makeRequest, 1000, button_id);
}

function makeRequest(button){
  //your XHTML Request here
}

//Stop the interval
function intervalShouldStop(){
  clearInterval(intervalToRun);
}
```

Take note: Internet Explorer versions 9 and below do not support the passing of arguments to the callback function in either setTimeout() or setInterval() link to pollyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval